# Open submission journals/repositories

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, tzibur-community, publications

When one is a student at a Jewish school (or, sometimes, one with a Jewish Studies department), if they are working on a research paper about Judaism, they can often publish it for feedback and acclaim through a student journal (e.g. [Kol Hamevaser](http://www.kolhamevaser.com)).

What can someone not in that position do to share their Judaism paper? I'm thinking something like an open-submission journal or blog, or a repository like arXiv.

Comment: What makes a journal an "open-submission journal"? Would a peer-reviewed academic journal that accepts submissions from anyone meet your creteria?

Comment: Anyone can start his own blog and share through social media.

Comment: @rosends if you don't have a following, no one will ever see it. At least with arXiv, for example, papers have built in communities and a permanent searchable home.

Comment: @Arithmomaniac self-promotion through social media. No one starts with an automatic following. Cross posting on groups that have the target audience, or towards friends encourages feedback and review.

Comment: If you ask a good question and have a good answer, you can always post it here!!

Comment: **How is this too broad??**

Comment: @ShmuelBrin perhaps because there is no one right answer to it; there could be many many answers: _if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to relate to Judaism but rather to getting published.

Answer (score 0):

For papers heavily based on primary texts quotations, one can use the [Sefaria Source Sheet Builder](http://www.sefaria.org/sheets?lang=bi). If you make a sheet public, it can be viewed by others via referenced text, tag, or "trending".

Comment: Still would like a more general purpose site, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more of a "peer-reviewed" journal, [Haoros UBiurium](http://haoros.com/cgi-bin/default.asp) of [Oholei Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oholei_Torah) takes outside contributions.

Answer (score -3):

arXiv is good. You can also probably put it on archive.org.

Comment: Judaism does not appear to be one of the subjects hosted by arXiv.

Comment: Is there some policy there which forbids such articles? I know for sure though, that you can find Judaism focused articles on SciHub. See [an example here](https://sci-hub.io/10.1080/01445340.2010.506106).